# Join same table twice for count in different columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables

```
A
+----+-------+
| Id | User  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | user1 |
|  2 | user2 |
|  3 | user3 |
+----+-------+

B
+----+--------+------+
| Id | UserId | Type |
+----+--------+------+
|  1 |      1 | A    |
|  2 |      1 | B    |
|  3 |      1 | C    |
|  4 |      2 | A    |
|  5 |      2 | B    |
|  6 |      2 | C    |
|  7 |      3 | A    |
|  8 |      3 | C    |
+----+--------+------+

UserId is FK from table A.Id
```

I'm trying to get count of each type and type permutations as below with single SQL query. (e.g count A^B means that number of users who has type A and B)

```
+---------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| Count A | Count B | Count C | Count A^B | Count A^C | Count B^C | Count A^B^C |
+---------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|       3 |       2 |       3 |         2 |         3 |         2 |           2 |
+---------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
```

Or separate query for each permutation count.

I tried below query to get count for type A and B separately and it didn't work.

```
SELECT count(b1.type) AS count_a, count(b2.type) AS count_b FROM A 
JOIN B on A.id = B.user_id
WHERE b1.type = 'A' or b2.type = 'B' 
GROUP BY A.id;

+---------+---------+
| Count A | Count B |
+---------+---------+
|       3 |       2 |
+---------+---------+
```

Comment: I'm not sure where the two tables come in or what the `^` represents

Comment: @ExplosionPills those are just column aliases.

Comment: I updated question. Hopefully it will explain better.
Basically, count A^B means that number of users who has type A and B

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write:

```
select count(case when "Types" @> array['A'] then 1 end) as "COUNT A",
       count(case when "Types" @> array['B'] then 1 end) as "COUNT B",
       count(case when "Types" @> array['C'] then 1 end) as "COUNT C",
       count(case when "Types" @> array['A','B'] then 1 end) as "COUNT A^B",
       count(case when "Types" @> array['A','C'] then 1 end) as "COUNT A^C",
       count(case when "Types" @> array['B','C'] then 1 end) as "COUNT B^C",
       count(case when "Types" @> array['A','B','C'] then 1 end) as "COUNT A^B^C"
  from ( select array_agg("Type"::text) as "Types"
           from "B"
          group by "UserId"
       ) t
;
```

The idea is that first we use a subquery that produces, for each user, an array containing his/her types; the outer query then just counts the arrays that contain each set of types.

You can see it in action at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cbb45/1. (I've also included there a modified version of the subquery, to help you see how it works.)

Some relevant PostreSQL documentation:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-aggregate.html (explains `array_agg`)
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html (explains `@>`)

Comment: This is very nice. Would we want COUNT() here, or SUM()?

Comment: This query does exactly what I needed. Thanks a mil!

Comment: @PittsburghDBA: It doesn't matter. I prefer COUNT() when the intent is counting -- it seems hackish to me to SUM() 1s and 0s in order to count 1s -- but a lot of people seem to prefer SUM() for everything except COUNT(\*). \*shrug\* They both work.

Comment: @ruakh Thanks. I was wondering what the behavior would be on this platform in particular. Some will add an informational error to the result stream when omitting NULL in an aggregate, for example. That's why I asked (best practices and all).

Comment: @PittsburghDBA: I don't know which RDBMSes you've used that "will add an informational error to the result stream when omitting NULL in an aggregate"; but I have to imagine that COUNT is an exception to that. I mean, the whole definition of COUNT is that it counts the non-NULL values. (This is why COUNT(NULL), for example, is 0 instead of NULL.)

Comment: No need to be on a high-horse, big shot. Here is an example of SQL Server doing exactly this behavior. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190368.aspx, hence the reason for my question, to see if this behavior lurked in PostgreSQL. Good grief.

Comment: @PittsburghDBA: I'm sorry if my comment offended you. I didn't mean "to be on a high-horse", or act like a "big shot"; and re-reading my comment now, I still have no idea what part of it gave you that impression. :-/

Comment: @PittsburghDBA: And, thanks for the link. That page indicates that 'COUNT' *does* have this behavior in Transact-SQL. Bizarre! (What's more, the page seems to be implying that ANSI/ISO advocates such a warning? I'm not sure.)

Comment: @ruakh I'm sorry that I misinterpreted your response. I took it the wrong way. That behavior of COUNT() on MSSQL is very aggravating, hence we look out for it when working with that platform. I don't know what the ANSI/ISO perspective is, but it's always worth a look for quirks like this. In these types of cases, I have preferred SUM() with CASE 1/0 for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am interpreting this wrong, but I think you can do a pretty simple case statement in your select statement, but rather than count do a SUM:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE b.Types WHEN 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0) as COUNT_A,
       SUM(CASE b.Types WHEN 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0) as COUNT_B
FROM  A 
JOIN B
ON A.id = B.user_id
WHERE b1.type = 'A' or b2.type = 'B'
```